# How can Excel do conditional formatting based on a comparison with the above cell?

Tags: excel

I have a table which is supposed to have a sequential id number at the beginning as in 1,2,3,4,5,6....

HOWEVER, during the export of the data, there appears to have been a bug which pastes two rows on just one row thus breaking the sequence. I am trying to identify these rows by conditonal format and am currently using this formula which is not working:

```
 ="IF($A2+1==$A3,TRUE,FALSE)"
 # Note the +1 is to account for the header row
```

I have tried moving the "$" around, but still no cigar.

My other option is to compare the sequence to the row number as in:

```
 ="IF($A2+1=ROWS($A1), TRUE, FALSE)
```

but that hasen't worked either.

I'm guessing it has to do with

I am trying to conditionally format the column so that I can identify where I need to insert a row and make a copy paste.

Right now, I am trying to use conditional formatting but am failing in this regard. I don't know how to use VBA so as of now, I would prefer to use the menu before getting into VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an `IF` formula in the conditional formatting, try this:

```
=A2+1<>A3
```

Somewhat crude, but should do what you want (i.e. highlight the cells that break the sequence).

[image]

Comment: What does the <> operator mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your `==` and your `"`, your formulas should work, but as Rocket Donkey put it, your condition will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` anyway, so you can remove the IF structure altogether.

Comment: i need to remove the ==, and replace it with what?